# Optoplanner vs jsprit vs Google OR tools

Tags: java, constraint-programming, or-tools, jsprit

I am trying to sovle TSP with time window constraints. I am evaluating the below tools.

1. OptaPlanner - supported by Jboss community. not specific to TRP but general constraint solver engine.
2. Jsprit - not sure about its support. its developed by GraphHopper? its listed one of the subprojects of Graph Hopper in GitHub.
3. Google OR tools - it is written in c++. But can run in java.

what are the advantages & disadvantages for each of the above tool. is there any better open source/paid tool available in market?

Comment: For OptaPlanner, take a look [at this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BxO3UFmtAPg) and the code behind that example. That being said, StackOverflow discourages opinion based questions like this, IIRC.

Comment: Thanks Geoffrey for the answer.I am aware that this may turn like a opinion based. but we are here to learn from each other's experience.

Comment: Yes - but I 've seen many similar questions be closed for this reason, because it's mentioned explicitly in the SO guidelines. Don't shoot the messenger :) IIRC there might a StackExchange site for opinion based questions too.

Comment: Thanks Geoffrey. I have posted new question here.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40302555/optoplanner-jsprit-tsptw-with-real-road-distance

Comment: Recommendations for tools is off-topic for stack overflow