# TSPTW with real road distance

Tags: optaplanner, constraint-programming, kie, vehicle-routing, jsprit

Is it possible to solve **asymmetric** **-travelling salesman problem with time window** (with the real road distances) with OptaPlanner or jsprit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With OptaPlanner, there is a Vehicle Routing Problem example that supports asymmetric distances and time windows. So just give it only 1 vehicle and you got the Traveling Sales Man variant of that.

Look for the code [in this directory](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/tree/master/optaplanner-examples/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/examples/vehiclerouting/domain): see `RoadLocation` (which supports asymmetric distances between them), `TimeWindowedCustomer` (which is a stopping point for the salesman) and `Vehicle` (which is the salesman).